# Android rounded button weird differences

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button

I have noticed a weird difference in behaviour between `Button` and `AppCompatButton` when they are given a background at runtime and when they are not.

I generated a rounded corners drawable from a square image in the asset folder

```kotlin
fun getRoundedBackground(context: Context) =
    context.assets.open("buttonBg.png").use {
        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.resources, it).apply {
            cornerRadius = 200f
        }
    }
```

Then I placed in my layout 2 `Button` and 2 `AppCompatButton` and then at runtime I applied my rounded background to one `Button` and to one `AppCompatButton`, leaving the other two default

```kotlin
// button1 does not get bg set
button2.background = getRoundedBackground(context)
// appCompatButton1 does not get bg set
appCompatButton2.background = getRoundedBackground(context)
```

This resulted in the following (on an Android 30 emulator)

[image]

In this screenshot I see:

1. The `Button` WITHOUT bg set gets the colour from the `colorPrimary` (why not default grey?)
2. The `Button` WITH bg set does not get the drawable but only its shape with rounded corners (WHAT? WHY?)
3. The `AppCompatButton` WITHOUT bg set gets the normal default colour (expected)
4. The `AppCompatButton` WITH bg set gets the right drawable all the way (expected)

Does somebody know why? (point 1 and 2)

Comment: If you're running this in an `AppCompatActivity` with a `MaterialComponents` theme, then your `<Button>`s are ending up as [`MaterialButton`s](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton), which handles its background with the new shape APIs instead.

Comment: Thanks Mike, although it is still strange to me that it's not applied homogeneously to AppCompatButtons and Buttons

Comment: I just realized that the answer I'd linked is not the one I thought (which I can't find atm), but the rest of that comment was still pertinent: only `<Button>` tags result in `MaterialButton`s; specifying `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>` will give you an `AppCompatButton`. It's not very intuitive, I know, and it's ridiculous that `MaterialButton` is silently substituted like that now, given its abnormal behavior, but that's just how things ended up after multiple iterations of the support library system. (Btw, if you want a plain `Button` you can use `<android.widget.Button>`.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarity Mike, the behaviour, although surprising for its sneakiness, does explain a few things. One thing I have not yet understood though is why the second `Button` (which then with the Material theme becomes a `MaterialButton` gets the shape but not the colour of the background I assigned to it

Comment: Though the docs only say ["Do not use the `android:background` attribute."](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#:~:text=Do%20not%20use%20the%20android%3Abackground%20attribute.), it actually means to not set a background yourself at all, whether in the XML or in code, since "`MaterialButton` cannot guarantee well-defined behavior" in that case.

Comment: You're likely getting [warnings in your logs saying basically the same thing](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.java#L424). If you're looking for the specific, low-level details to explain the observed behavior, that class and `MaterialButtonHelper` would be the place to start.